# I cant see label in input field and when i choose option from list is the id not added to list of fieldPath its generic component with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete, frontend

I cant see label in input field and when i choose option from list is the id not added to list of fieldPath
its generic component with react

```
type SelectOption = {
  label: ReactNode;
  value: string;
};

export type FormAutocompleteProps<T extends FieldValues> = Omit<FormTextFieldProps<T>, "name"> & {
  options: SelectOption[];
  name: FieldPath<T>;
};

export function FormAutocomplete<T extends FieldValues>({
  name,
  size,
  label,
  fullWidth,
  options,
  ...props
}: FormAutocompleteProps<T>) {
  const { formState: { errors }, control, setValue, watch } = useFormContext<T>();
  const error = _.get(errors, name) as FieldError;
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Typography className={styles.label}>{label}</Typography>
      <Controller
        name={name}
        control={control}
        render={({ field }) => (
          <Autocomplete
            noOptionsText={t('code_0001_1')}
            multiple
            limitTags={4}
            value={field.value}
            getOptionLabel={(option) => option.label as string}
            options={options}
            isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option.value === value.value}
            onChange={(event, newValue) => {
              setValue(name, watch(name));
              field.onChange(newValue);
            }}
            renderOption={(props, option) => (
              <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value} {...props}>
                <Typography >{option.label}</Typography>
              </MenuItem>
            )}
            size={size || "small"}
            popupIcon={<KeyboardArrowDownIcon className={styles.arrow} />}
            renderInput={(params) => (
              <TextField
                {...params}
                size="small"
                error={Boolean(error)}
                helperText={error?.message as string}
                value={options.find((option) => option.value === field.value)?.label || ''}
                {...props}
              />
            )}
          />
        )}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

I cant see label in input field and when i choose option from list is the id not added to list of fieldPath
its generic component with react